# Apex report full text search unable to apply scoring

Tags: sql, plsql, full-text-search, oracle-apex

i'm having some trouble and I can't find a straight answer when searching online. 
I am using oracle apex 5.1.3, im writing up some plsql for a report with full text search, but can't seem to apply score to it, i know im making a blonde mistake but i know the base query works.

This is my original query

```
SELECT VENUE_NAME, CITY, POSTCODE, score(1) + score(2) as score
FROM GAMEVENUE
WHERE
(
CONTAINS(VENUE_NAME, '$FUZZY(plymouth)', 1) > 0 
OR CONTAINS(CITY, '$FUZZY(plymouth)', 2) > 0 
OR CONTAINS(POSTCODE, 'plymouth') > 0
)
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This is where the problems lie, any help would be great.

*Parsing returned query results in "ORA-06550: line 9, column 11: ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator". If you believe your query is syntactically correct, check the "Use Generic Column Names" checkbox below to proceed without parsing.*

```
DECLARE

  l_query VARCHAR2 (4096);

BEGIN

  l_query := '
                select 
                "VENUE_ID",
                "VENUE_NAME",
                "CITY",
                "VENUE_NO",
                "POSTCODE",
                dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
                score(1) + score(2) as score
                 FROM   "GAMEVENUE" i';

  IF v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') IS NOT NULL THEN
    l_query := l_query||' '||'
    where 
    (   
 contains(VENUE_NAME, ''$fuzzy('|| v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') ||'), 1'') > 0 or
 contains(CITY, ''$fuzzy('|| v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') ||'), 2'') > 0 or
 contains(POSTCODE, '''|| v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') ||''') > 0 
    )
   ORDER BY score DESC';
  END IF;

  RETURN l_query;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator
```

means you are actually running a query like this:

```
select 
            "VENUE_ID",
            "VENUE_NAME",
            "CITY",
            "VENUE_NO",
            "POSTCODE",
            dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
            score(1) + score(2) as score
             FROM   "GAMEVENUE" i
```

In other words, you have missed out the `WHERE` clause, probably because of this IF statement:

```
IF v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') IS NOT NULL THEN
  l_query := l_query||' '||'
  where ...
```

What you probably want to do is avoid calling `score()` if the where clause is not being added, e.g.

```
if v('P2_REPORT_SEARCH') is not null then
   l_selectscore := 'score(1) + score(2)';
else
   l_selectscore := 'null';
end if;

l_query := '
            select 
            "VENUE_ID",
            "VENUE_NAME",
            "CITY",
            "VENUE_NO",
            "POSTCODE",
            dbms_lob.getlength("THUMBNAIL") "THUMBNAIL",
            ' || l_select_score || ' as score
             FROM   "GAMEVENUE" i';
```